# StaggeredGridLayout messes up when scrolling up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I made this `StaggeredGridLayout` for my `RecyclerView`: 
[image]

Here's the code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    Photo photo = mPhotos.get(position);

    TextView titleView = ((CellViewHolder) viewHolder).titleTextView;
        titleView.setText(photo.getTitle());

    TextView subTitleView = ((CellViewHolder) viewHolder).subtitleTextView;
        subTitleView.setText(photo.getName());

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(photo.getPhotoUrl()).into(((CellViewHolder) viewHolder).imageView);

    ImageView userImageOverlay = ((CellViewHolder) viewHolder).userImageOverlay;

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();

    if (position == 0 || position % 4 == 0) {
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
        layoutParams.height = Math.round(Utils.convertDpToPixel(202.67f, mContext));
        titleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 21.67f);
        subTitleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12.00f);
        userImageOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if ((position - 1) % 4 == 0) {
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
        layoutParams.height = Math.round(Utils.convertDpToPixel(360.00f, mContext));
        titleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15.00f);
        subTitleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10.00f);
        userImageOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
        layoutParams.height = Math.round(Utils.convertDpToPixel(180.00f, mContext));
        titleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15.00f);
        subTitleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10.00f);
        userImageOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except when I scroll it up. It draws cells by position in descending order and it leaves empty spaces in grid:

[image]

**Any ideas how to keep the same pattern even scrolling it up?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
manager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

or:[change position when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273295/android-recyclerview-staggeredgrid-items-change-position-when-scrolling-top/36759012#36759012)

or:github project [Picasso/Glide-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/yuvaraj119/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the [gap strategy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#setGapStrategy(int))

```
mLayoutMang.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
```

`GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS` will update the layous when the scroll state is changed to idle

Comment: I set GapStrategy before setting layout manager to recyclerView, but it gives no effect. Still the same.

Comment: @Roo hmm, I am not sure what you are doing with dynamically adjusting item sizes is exactly recommended in recyclerview but I could be wrong

Comment: @Roo maybe instead of dynamically changing the height of the cell, make the cell have 2 imageviews in one and just hide one of them when you hit your condition `(position - 1) % 4 == 0` or inflate another view in the position

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856036/how-to-reflow-items-in-a-recyclerview-with-the-staggeredgridlayoutmanager