# Possibility of designing grid page with varying rows for each columns

Tags: android, wear-os

I have one more quick question. Should the GridPageAdapater always be x X y (3 x 2 or 4 x 4) with x rows and y columns? Could it be, for example, 1st column has only 1 row, second column has 3 rows? Is it possible to design it that way, and if so, how?

Comment: Search for staggered grid. Here's a layoutmanager that will help with that https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/35859153/2270271 for another method.

Comment: But I want this to be implemented with CardFragments in smartwatch. So as I navigate horizontally or vertically corresponding cardFragements should be shown. I will make it easier to understand. In this link learnandroidwear.com/gridviewpager-cardfragment you can see 9 cardFragments. Among them I need only (0,0), (0,1),(1,1),(2,1) and (0,2). Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible with a `GridView`, but you could do something similar with a `TableLayout`. This `View` has an atrribute called `android:layout_span', in which you can specify the amount of columns an item will span (take up). You could use this to your advantage to just set the size to the maximum number of columns you will have in a row and just span everything else. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) is an example of how this could be demonstrated, and the documentation is located [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: But I want this to be implemented with CardFragments in smartwatch. So as I navigate horizontally or vertically corresponding cardFragements should be shown. I will make it easier to understand. In this link http://www.learnandroidwear.com/gridviewpager-cardfragment/ you can see 9 cardFragments. Among them I need only (0,0), (0,1),(1,1),(2,1) and (0,2). Is this possible.